# A series of ifelse statements incorrectly defaults to the last option with real not simulated data

Tags: r, function, if-statement, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that will uses values from variables stored in different columns to generate a new variable. The logic requires a series of `ifelse` statements.  However, the final statement is always evaluating to `true` and I don't understand why.

Even more puzzling when I generated data for the MWE then the function works fine. But it still behaves bizarrely with a sample from the real data. I am guessing there is something in my environment that is causing mischief but I am now lost as how to investigate further.

FWIW I have tried writing this function in `data.table` and now `dplyr` syntax, and I get similar problems with both approaches.

Simpler functions that don't use `ifelse` statements seem to behave just fine.

```
gen_sofa_c <- function(data, map=NA, noradr=NA, dopa=NA, adr=NA, vasopressin=NA) {
    library(dplyr)

    # Extract the arguments and force conversion to string
    pars <- as.list(match.call()[-1])

    vasopressin <- as.character(pars$vasopressin)
    noradr <- as.character(pars$noradr)
    adr <- as.character(pars$adr)
    dopa <- as.character(pars$dopa)
    map <- as.character(pars$map)

    # Default to NA
    # if ("sofa_c" %in% names(data)) data$sofa_c <- NULL
    # data$sofa_c <- as.numeric(NA)

    return(

        data %>% 

        # # Return 0 if MAP >= 70
        mutate(sofa_c = ifelse(!is.na(map) & map >= 70, 0 , NA)) %>%

        # # Return 1 if MAP < 70
        mutate(sofa_c = ifelse(!is.na(map) & map < 70, 1 , sofa_c)) %>%

        # # Return SOFA 2 if norad OR adr > 0.0 or dopamine > 5
        mutate(sofa_c = ifelse(!is.na(noradr) & noradr > 0.0 , 2 , sofa_c)) %>%

        # # Return SOFA 3 if norad OR adr > 0.1 or dopamine > 15
        mutate(sofa_c = ifelse(!is.na(noradr) & noradr > 0.1 , 3 , sofa_c)) %>%

        # # Return SOFA 4 if on vasopressin
        mutate(sofa_c = ifelse(!is.na(vasopressin) & vasopressin > 0, 4 , sofa_c)) %>%

        # Return sofa_c
        select(sofa_c)
   )
}
```

Here is the simulated data

```
# Simulate data
set.seed(1234)
tdata <- data.table(map=round(rnorm(100,70,10)), noradr=round(rnorm(100,0,1),2), vasopressin=sample(c(rep(NA,9),1)))
tdata[, noradr := ifelse(noradr < 0, NA, noradr)]
sofa_c <-  gen_sofa_c(tdata, map=map, noradr=rx_norad, dopa=rx_dopa, adr=rx_adre, vasopressin=rx_vasopr) 
table(sofa_c)
(cbind(tdata, sofa_c))
```

My output is this

```
R> table(sofa_c)
sofa_c
 0  1  2  3  4 
17 27  4 42 10 
R> head((cbind(tdata, sofa_c)),10)
    map noradr vasopressin sofa_c
 1:  58   0.41          NA      3
 2:  73     NA          NA      0
 3:  81   0.07           1      4
 4:  47     NA          NA      1
 5:  74     NA          NA      0
 6:  75   0.17          NA      3
 7:  64     NA          NA      1
 8:  65   0.17          NA      3
 9:  64   0.35          NA      3
10:  61     NA          NA      1
```

Here is the real data (as sample from >2 million rows)

```
nrow(ddata)
rdata <- ddata[runif(100,1,nrow(ddata)),.(map,norad=rx_norad,vasopressin=rx_vasopr)]
dput(rdata)
rm(sofa_c)
sofa_c <-  gen_sofa_c(rdata, map=map, noradr=rx_norad, dopa=rx_dopa, adr=rx_adre, vasopressin=rx_vasopr) 
table(sofa_c)
head((cbind(rdata, sofa_c)),10)
```

Here is the sample from the real data

```
R> dput(rdata)
structure(list(map = c(80, 82, 76, NA, 87, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 124, 65, 63, NA, 70, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
100, NA, NA, NA, NA, 85, 85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 97, 84, 0, 84, NA, 75, NA, NA, NA, 67, NA, 58, NA, 153, 
122, NA, NA, 91, 90, NA, NA, 87, NA, 60, 72, 107, 62, NA, NA, 
97, 88, NA, NA, NA, 60, 81, 80, NA, NA, 82, 72, NA, 98, NA, NA, 
80, 82, NA, NA, NA, 68, NA, NA, 126, 90, 65, 67, NA), norad = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.18, 0.00952381, NA, NA, 0.12962963, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.172222, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0623529, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.29005848, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.221667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.284444444, NA, NA, 0.19, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
4, NA, NA), vasopressin = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("map", 
"norad", "vasopressin"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x101810978>)
```

Here is the real data output

```
R> table(sofa_c)
sofa_c
 3  4 
99  1 
R> head((cbind(rdata, sofa_c)),10)
    map norad vasopressin sofa_c
 1:  80    NA          NA      3
 2:  82    NA          NA      3
 3:  76    NA          NA      3
 4:  NA    NA          NA      3
 5:  87  0.00          NA      3
 6:  NA    NA          NA      3
 7:  NA    NA          NA      3
 8:  NA  0.14          NA      3
 9:  NA    NA          NA      3
10:  NA    NA          NA      3
```

Comment: You do realize that your `ifelse` statements are not exclusive and can overwrite previous results, right? I'm guessing you meant to have nested `ifelse` statements: `ifelse(condition1, 0, ifelse(condition2, 1, ...`

Comment: Thanks @eddi but that is why the second option in each statement is the pre-existing value. The series of statements is meant to update the value when `ifelse` evaluates as `TRUE` else keep the preexisting value. I thought about nesting but it makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: I'm trying to point out that's not the same thing as nesting. In your case you'd need to add `ifelse(is.na(sofa_c) & ...)` to each `ifelse` after the first one, to get the same results as with nesting.

Comment: Appreciate the advice but are you saying this because nesting is necessary to use the pre-existing value of the item within the ifelse statement? If I do `x<- 1:3` then `x <- ifelse(x==2,-2,x)`, then I get `[1]  1 -2  3` which would suggest that the non-nested logic I used _should_ work?

Comment: You're not following. Here's an example: `x = 1:3; y = ifelse(x < 2, 0, NA); y = ifelse(x < 3, 1, y)` vs `x = 1:3; y = ifelse(x < 2, 0, ifelse(x < 3, 1, NA))`. Same thing happens for e.g. your conditions 3, 4 vs 1, 2 - they're not independent. As I said earlier - alternative to nesting for the above example is `x = 1:3; y = ifelse(x < 2, 0, NA); y = ifelse(is.na(y) & x < 3, 1, y)`.

Comment: I'm mainly checking that you realize the difference between the two, since it sounds like that might be your issue.

Comment: The above aside, you have two other big issues. First, you have a typo in your column names in your data (norad instead of noradr). Second - you're **not** doing what you think you are when you create those character strings by doing `map = as.character(par$map)` and then use them. All that does is assign `map = "map"` and then the rest of your conditions become nonsense. So remove everything until your `return` statement, fix column names, and rethink your logic.

Comment: Thanks @eddi for spotting the typo and for correcting my attempt to parse the function arguments. Fixing these mistakes solved my problem! However, I didn't change the logic of the sequential `ifelse` statements in doing this, and I am getting the correct answer so although I understand the difference between your nested and non-nested statements, the approach I used seems OK. If you move your comment to an answer I can 'accept it'?